# Compiling mod_auth_mysql on snow leopard

Tags: apache2

How to build mod_auth_mysql on Snow Leopard?

Instead of burying my findings in some blog comment I decided to document them here in an answer.

I've got the following errors:

```
May 24 10:43:44 host org.apache.httpd[6764]: httpd: Syntax error on line 120 of /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf: Cannot load /usr/libexec/apache2/mod_auth_mysql.so into server: dlopen(/usr/libexec/apache2/mod_auth_mysql.so, 10): Symbol not found: _make_scrambled_password\n  Referenced from: /usr/libexec/apache2/mod_auth_mysql.so\n  Expected in: flat namespace\n in /usr/libexec/apache2/mod_auth_mysql.so
May 24 11:14:06 host org.apache.httpd[10880]: httpd: Syntax error on line 120 of /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf: Cannot load /usr/libexec/apache2/mod_auth_mysql.so into server: dlopen(/usr/libexec/apache2/mod_auth_mysql.so, 10): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib\n  Referenced from: /usr/libexec/apache2/mod_auth_mysql.so\n  Reason: image not found
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to tweak this slightly, so it would run on a Mac mini core duo (not capable of 64-bit code), essentially, you just have to omit the references to the 64 bit architecture:

```
$ sudo apxs -c -i -a -D lmysqlclient -lmysqlclient -lm -lz -I/usr/local/mysql/include/ \
-L/usr/local/mysql/lib/ mod_auth_mysql.c
```

If you get an error not finding cc of the XCode Toolchain:

> env: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.8.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc: No such file or directory
>   apxs:Error: Command failed with rc=65536

then you either have to install XCode at all, or symlink to the default toolchain:

```
$ sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.8.xctoolchain
```

Also: Nils Preusker's Blog is down. You might find the answer still in Google's caches. Alternatively, I have pasted the relevant portions here:

Compiling and Installing mod_auth_mysql on OS X 10.5.6

April 17th, 2009 by nils
The apche module mod_auth_mysql makes it possible to use a MySQL database instead of e.g. a passwd file. There is an installer of the module for Mac OS X 10.4, but no installation package or port for Mac OS X 10.5 or later. I played around with the sources a little bit and finally managed to get it to compile and apache to start without error messages. I’ve created a diff file to patch mod_auth_mysql.c. The following steps explain how to apply the patch, compile the module and test your apache configuration.

We’ll first create a src folder in your user directory, download mod_auth_mysql and expand it:

```
$ mkdir ~/src
$ cd ~/src
$ curl -O http://puzzle.dl.sourceforge.net/sourceforge/\
modauthmysql/mod_auth_mysql-3.0.0.tar.gz
$ tar zxvf mod_auth_mysql-3.0.0.tar.gz
```

Now you have the sources of the module in the folder mod_auth_mysql-3.0.0. Before we can compile it, the patch has to be applied. Here is the diff file [mod_auth_mysql](http://www.nilspreusker.de/wp-content/uploads/2009/04/mod_auth_mysql.diff), save it to

~/src/mod_auth_mysql-3.0.0/mod_auth_mysql.diff
To apply the patch, we change to the sources directory and execute the unix patch program that takes the original file and applies the diff file as patch:

```
$ cd mod_auth_mysql-3.0.0
$ patch mod_auth_mysql.c mod_auth_mysql.diff
```

continue with either 32 or 64 bit code...

In case the diff file goes missing, here it is...

```
209c209
<   #define STRCAT ap_pstrcat
---
>   #define STRCAT apr_pstrcat
592c592
<   (void *) APR_XtOffsetOf(mysql_auth_config_rec, mysqlhost),
---
>   (void *) APR_OFFSETOF(mysql_auth_config_rec, mysqlhost),
596c596
<   (void *) APR_XtOffsetOf(mysql_auth_config_rec, mysqlport),
---
>   (void *) APR_OFFSETOF(mysql_auth_config_rec, mysqlport),
600c600
<   (void *) APR_XtOffsetOf(mysql_auth_config_rec, mysqlsocket),
---
>   (void *) APR_OFFSETOF(mysql_auth_config_rec, mysqlsocket),
604c604
<   (void *) APR_XtOffsetOf(mysql_auth_config_rec, mysqluser),
---
>   (void *) APR_OFFSETOF(mysql_auth_config_rec, mysqluser),
608c608
<   (void *) APR_XtOffsetOf(mysql_auth_config_rec, mysqlpasswd),
---
>   (void *) APR_OFFSETOF(mysql_auth_config_rec, mysqlpasswd),
612c612
<   (void *) APR_XtOffsetOf(mysql_auth_config_rec, mysqlDB),
---
>   (void *) APR_OFFSETOF(mysql_auth_config_rec, mysqlDB),
616c616
<   (void *) APR_XtOffsetOf(mysql_auth_config_rec, mysqlpwtable),
---
>   (void *) APR_OFFSETOF(mysql_auth_config_rec, mysqlpwtable),
620c620
<   (void *) APR_XtOffsetOf(mysql_auth_config_rec, mysqlgrptable),
---
>   (void *) APR_OFFSETOF(mysql_auth_config_rec, mysqlgrptable),
624c624
<   (void *) APR_XtOffsetOf(mysql_auth_config_rec, mysqlNameField),
---
>   (void *) APR_OFFSETOF(mysql_auth_config_rec, mysqlNameField),
628c628
<   (void *) APR_XtOffsetOf(mysql_auth_config_rec, mysqlGroupField),
---
>   (void *) APR_OFFSETOF(mysql_auth_config_rec, mysqlGroupField),
632c632
<   (void *) APR_XtOffsetOf(mysql_auth_config_rec, mysqlGroupUserNameField),
---
>   (void *) APR_OFFSETOF(mysql_auth_config_rec, mysqlGroupUserNameField),
636c636
<   (void *) APR_XtOffsetOf(mysql_auth_config_rec, mysqlPasswordField),
---
>   (void *) APR_OFFSETOF(mysql_auth_config_rec, mysqlPasswordField),
640c640
<   (void *) APR_XtOffsetOf(mysql_auth_config_rec, mysqlEncryptionField),
---
>   (void *) APR_OFFSETOF(mysql_auth_config_rec, mysqlEncryptionField),
644c644
<   (void*) APR_XtOffsetOf(mysql_auth_config_rec, mysqlSaltField),
---
>   (void*) APR_OFFSETOF(mysql_auth_config_rec, mysqlSaltField),
652c652
<   (void *) APR_XtOffsetOf(mysql_auth_config_rec, mysqlAuthoritative),
---
>   (void *) APR_OFFSETOF(mysql_auth_config_rec, mysqlAuthoritative),
656c656
<   (void *) APR_XtOffsetOf(mysql_auth_config_rec, mysqlNoPasswd),
---
>   (void *) APR_OFFSETOF(mysql_auth_config_rec, mysqlNoPasswd),
660c660
<   (void *) APR_XtOffsetOf(mysql_auth_config_rec, mysqlEnable),
---
>   (void *) APR_OFFSETOF(mysql_auth_config_rec, mysqlEnable),
664c664
<   (void *) APR_XtOffsetOf(mysql_auth_config_rec, mysqlUserCondition),
---
>   (void *) APR_OFFSETOF(mysql_auth_config_rec, mysqlUserCondition),
668c668
<   (void *) APR_XtOffsetOf(mysql_auth_config_rec, mysqlGroupCondition),
---
>   (void *) APR_OFFSETOF(mysql_auth_config_rec, mysqlGroupCondition),
672c672
<   (void *) APR_XtOffsetOf(mysql_auth_config_rec, mysqlCharacterSet),
---
>   (void *) APR_OFFSETOF(mysql_auth_config_rec, mysqlCharacterSet),
```

Answer (score 0):

- First follow the instructions on [Nils Preusker's blog](http://www.nilspreusker.de/2009/04/17/compiling-and-installing-mod_auth_mysql-on-os-x-1056/), especially apply his patch.
- Check what path information is store in mysqls .dylib file

  - `otool -DX /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib`
  - this should return a full path, it doesnt you have to fix it first by calling
  - `sudo install_name_tool -id /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib  /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib`
- Add `-lmysqlclient` to the apxs command line:

**Compilation:**

```
sudo apxs -c -i -a -D lmysqlclient -lmysqlclient -lm -lz \ 
 -I/usr/local/mysql/include/ \
 -L/usr/local/mysql/lib/ -Wc,"-arch x86_64" \
 -Wl,"-arch x86_64" mod_auth_mysql.c
```

- Ensure the mysql library is listed: otool -L /usr/libexec/apache2/mod_auth_mysql.so
- Check your setup with apachectl configtest

Cheers!